# NLog.config file not string in the root directories.. Instead it is storing in bin directories while publishing

Tags: nlog, nlog.config

I am using NLog for the logging in my application. when I tried to publish my code the nlog.config file is saving in the bin directories. It is not storing in the root directories. Instead of storing bin I want to store the nlog.config file in the published root directories. Does anyone help me on this.. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Have you configured your NLog.config to have `CopyToPublishDirectory = PreserveNewest` in your csproj-file:

```
<ItemGroup>
  <Content Include="NLog.config" CopyToPublishDirectory="PreserveNewest" />
</ItemGroup>
```